# CosmosDB Request charge differs dramatically for same query, same collection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection of 7 documents. 6 docs are about 1kb size and one is about 15kb.
Documents have a field named `Email`.

In Azure portal, in CosmosDB data explorer, i do simple query:

`{"Email":/^co*/}`

This returns all documents whose `Email` property starts with `co` (in this case its always 1 document returned). Now, when i run this query repeatedly, i get RU charges that vary from 6.98 to 104.99!
I emphasise, all of this happen in CosmosDB data explorer in Azure portal. Collection doesn't change during test. Noone else does any db queries while i am running tests.

Now this is complete mistery for me. I thought request charge is deterministic and that if collection and query don't change that request charge would be the same. This is 15 times different.

Does anyone have any explanation?

Comment: When you say "repeatedly" are you trying the same query in rapid succession (e.g. 1-2x per second?)

Comment: good point, thanks for asking that. no, i was careful to never fire more than one request per second. although, this is not about total RU spent per second. Request charge i've written is charge per query.

Comment: Maybe its a bug in the portal? Did you try it in a standalone application?

Comment: thanks for your comment! yes i've tried both: in portal and by examining requestCharge header in response to query request. same results. so, its not a bug in portal.

Comment: Have you examined the metrics header requested by `x-ms-documentdb-populatequerymetrics` for those heavy-RU-rated requests?

Comment: i was using mongodb c# and mongodb api on cosmosdb. in that case there is a command GetLastRequestChare and thats what i examined. as i said, i also tried same query directly in data explorer in azure portal and got the same result.